# How to publish a Quarto website to an intranet web server?

Tags: intranet, quarto

I can't find anything on this subject besides it being possible as per [Quarto's guide](https://quarto.org/docs/publishing/other.html).

I have built a website through Quarto and GitHub before, so I have experience on the Quarto side of things. But are there tips for getting a website on an intranet web server, for a complete newbie to intranet web servers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just like any other static site generator, Quarto creates a directory full of HTML files and resources (by default it's `_site` dir, as far as I can see).  Its content is supposed to be ready to be dropped into a directory and served by any half-decent web server.  So if we talking about starting from scratch:

0. Find a server
1. Set up DNS so that `your.intranet.server` address resolves to the server's IP address properly
2. Install and run a Web server (*nginx* is one of the most popular choices)
3. Check server config to see what directory is served by default (for *nginx* it's usually something like `/usr/share/nginx/html`)
4. Copy the contents of your `_site/` into that default directory.

It is by no means a full tutorial but should get you started, hopefully.

Comment: Glad I asked as I am unfamiliar with a lot of terms. Specifically I will do some research regarding 1-3. Thanks!

Comment: this is a good answer as it is succinct and to the point. I would only add that if you have an organisation intranet, you could ask your system administrator to provide you with 1) local resolving domain name (DNS), 2) with a directory on the intranet web server where you could just drop your site and it would be served under that DNS name. If you get it working once under the sysadmin's supervision, then in the future all you have to do would be to replace site files when you have a new page added/edited on your site. I prefer `rsync` for those updates.

Comment: @r0berts, yep, it's a good option indeed.  I decided against going into much details, because there's so many ways to do that, but what you described is absolutely a valid strategy