# How do I run a Quarto website from a Shiny Server

Tags: r, shiny-server, quarto

I created a Quarto website [here](https://josephjefe.quarto.pub/jefes-handiwork/) that included links to several Shiny apps I had made and hosted on shinyapps io. I had been wanting to host my own server and put them there instead, and finally did that. I set up a shiny server on DigitalOcean (Ubuntu 22.04), and my apps are now hosted there, and everything with that part works fine. However, I wanted to also move the website from quarto.pub to my new shiny server, as it has multiple explainers/tutorials on how to use the apps, as well as a navbar and sidebar that the shiny apps don't. I tried to simply copy/paste the entire contents of the website project into the svr/shiny-server folder and replace the default index.html page with the index.qmd page from the quarto website project. The index.qmd part works. It reads everything in the index.qmd file, but it's not reading the _quarto.yml file at all, so the navbar and sidebar are gone. You can see that [here](https://www.jefeshandiwork.com/). It is also not creating the other pages that you can navigate to from the quarto.pub website. Is there a different location I need to save the _quarto.yml document to?

How do I properly port over my quarto website into my new shiny server so that it has the navigational options that my quarto.pub site does?

Answer (score 0):

I you are going to self host your Shiny app and your Quarto website, you should be more familiar of how the web server works.

For Quarto, you probably want to use NGINX or Apache to host the HTML files that you built.

Without knowing too much of the ShinyProxy offer from DigitalOcean, I believe that it rendering your `index.qmd` as Markdown file. This is why you don't get the navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

[This stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75923471/how-to-publish-a-quarto-website-to-an-intranet-web-server) provided a very clear breakdown of exactly how to post the quarto docs from your project into the server to turn it into a website. Essentially, figure out what folder the default landing page lives in (find the "index.html" page that you would edit to change the home page in the NGINX server), delete the original "index.html" page, and paste the contents of the "_site" folder from your Quarto project there.